# PayPal cart contents for Magento 2 bundled products

Tags: magento2, paypal-standard

So the issue I have is with gift hampers on my site. They are set up as bundled products with drop-down selections e.g. '4 Piece Hamper' {product1, product2, product3, product4;}. However, inside the PayPal Transaction Details Page for each order it only displays '4 Piece Hamper' (without it's actual selections).

I understand that usually orders and their details would be extracted from the E-Commerce CMS dashboard, however my client is 'technologically challenged', and isn't willing to change their procedures.

Previous to this project with Magento CE, we had to store the bundled products in an array and display them in the PayPal product description I believe, but this had its limitations due the top character limit limiting the number of options a hamper could have to display its options in PayPal.

Is there any way around this issue?

Thanks a lot,
William.